# VS Code-NodeJS- live-server issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I'm getting below error while running live-server in VS Code after installing NodeJS though it is properly showing me the version of NodeJS after hitting node -v**

live-server : The term 'live-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- live-server
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (live-server:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

....................